# How to write arabic text using manim

Tags: manim

I have installed lualatex so I can write arabic using manim but I am having trouble understanding how to use it and set it up in manim.

I tried using the command class TexTemplate(tex_compiler="lualatex") but this didn't work and I don't know what else to do. Please Help!

Comment: https://fajrulf.medium.com/how-to-install-manim-566034f96631

Answer (score 0):

you don't need luatext, any half-decent, modern LaTeX distribution will work.

```py
# https://discord.com/channels/581738731934056449/1104675869340999741/1104853869932060762
from manim import *
class MultipleFonts5(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        ArabTexTemplate = TexTemplate(
            tex_compiler="xelatex",   
            output_format='.xdv',            
            preamble = r'''
\usepackage{polyglossia}\setotherlanguage{arabic}\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Noto Naskh Arabic}
            '''
        )
        UrduTexTemplate = TexTemplate(
            tex_compiler="xelatex",   
            output_format='.xdv',            
            preamble = r'''
\usepackage{polyglossia}\setotherlanguage{arabic}\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Noto Nastaliq Urdu}
            '''
        )
        arabicText = Tex(
            r"عابدات",
            tex_template=ArabTexTemplate,
            tex_environment="Arabic"
        ).shift(UP)
        self.add(arabicText)
        urduText = Tex(
            r"عابد",
            tex_template=UrduTexTemplate,
            tex_environment="Arabic"
        ).shift(DOWN)
        self.add(urduText)
```

You will need the corresponding fonts containing arabic letters as well at the LaTeX package polyglossia.

Come over to [Discord](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/faq/general.html?highlight=discord#where-can-i-find-more-resources-for-learning-manim) for more information on Manim.

[image]